# Elasticsearch - Filters not working

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to build a query to return all products of a genre:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://172.17.0.2:9200/products/_search?pretty' -d '
{
"query" : {
    "filtered" : { 
        "query" : {
            "match_all" : {} 
        },
        "filter" : {
            "term" : { 
                "genre" : "Feminino"
            }
        }
    }
}
}'
```

but the result is zero products. The query doesn't return anything.
If I remove the filter assignment the query works:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://172.17.0.2:9200/products/_search?pretty' -d '
{
"query" : {
    "filtered" : { 
        "query" : {
            "match_all" : {} 
        }
    }
}
}'
```

The setting of my index are:

```
curl -s http://172.17.0.2:9200/products/_settings |python -m json.tool
{
"products": {
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "creation_date": "1455635219340",
            "number_of_replicas": "1",
            "number_of_shards": "5",
            "products": {
                "mappings": {
                    "properties": {
                        "avaliability": {
                            "index": "not_analyzed",
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "best_seller": {
                            "index": "not_analyzed",
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "brand": {
                            "index": "not_analyzed",
                            "type": "double"
                        },
                        "brand_lenses": {
                            "index": "not_analyzed",
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "category": {
                            "index": "not_analyzed",
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "color": {
                            "index": "not_analyzed",
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "color_arm": {
                            "index": "not_analyzed",
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "color_lense": {
                            "index": "not_analyzed",
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "description": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "duration": {
                            "index": "not_analyzed",
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "final_price": {
                            "index": "not_analyzed",
                            "type": "double"
                        },
                        "format": {
                            "index": "not_analyzed",
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "front_image": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "genre": {
                            "index": "not_analyzed",
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "installment_amount": {
                            "index": "not_analyzed",
                            "type": "double"
                        },
                        "installment_times": {
                            "index": "not_analyzed",
                            "type": "integer"
                        },
                        "lenses_type": {
                            "index": "not_analyzed",
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "link": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "manufacturer": {
                            "index": "not_analyzed",
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "material": {
                            "index": "not_analyzed",
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "model": {
                            "index": "not_analyzed",
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "name": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "new": {
                            "index": "not_analyzed",
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "pathology": {
                            "index": "not_analyzed",
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "price": {
                            "index": "not_analyzed",
                            "type": "double"
                        },
                        "price_in_cash": {
                            "index": "not_analyzed",
                            "type": "double"
                        },
                        "qty": {
                            "index": "not_analyzed",
                            "type": "integer"
                        },
                        "side_image": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "sku": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "toast": {
                            "index": "not_analyzed",
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "type": {
                            "index": "not_analyzed",
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "uuid": "jxYCUwUGSHW3Rj-A5Q0Tkg",
            "version": {
                "created": "2020099"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there something wrong in my query or in my index?

EDIT: The output of search without the filter:

```
curl -s -XPOST 'http://172.17.0.2:9200/products/_search?pretty&size=1' -d '
{
 "query" : {
     "filtered" : { 
         "query" : {
             "match_all" : {} 
         }
     }
 }
}' | python -m json.tool
{
"_shards": {
    "failed": 0,
    "successful": 5,
    "total": 5
},
"hits": {
    "hits": [
        {
            "_id": "30-2024-MMBQ1090_C4",
            "_index": "products",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "avaliability": "[out of stock]",
                "best_seller": "",
                "brand": "1.8.1",
                "category": "\u00d3culos de Grau",
                "color": "Marrom",
                "color_arm": "Marrom",
                "color_lense": "",
                "description": "Esse charmoso \u00f3culos possui a super tend\u00eancia cor marsala, um vinho mais fechado pro marrom, que transmite eleg\u00e2ncia imediata. Al\u00e9m disso, na lateral da sua haste ele mostra um detalhe met\u00e1lico incr\u00edvel, que enche esse modelo de personalidade. Seu formato retangular d\u00e1 o toque final de estilo contempor\u00e2neo. Muito belo! preencher",
                "final_price": 197.0,
                "format": "Retangular",
                "front_image": "https://media.eotica.com.br/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/266x120/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/o/c/oculos-181-mmbq1090p-c4-1-rn.jpg",
                "genre": [
                    "Feminino",
                    "Masculino"
                ],
                "id": "30-2024-MMBQ1090_C4",
                "installment_amount": 65.67,
                "installment_times": "3",
                "lenses_type": "",
                "link": "https://www.eotica.com.br/oculos-de-grau-181-jacob-mmbq-1090-marrom-c4.html",
                "material": "N\u00e3o Metal",
                "model": "MMBQ1090 ",
                "name": "181 Jacob MMBQ1090 - Marrom - C4 - \u00d3culos de Grau",
                "new": "",
                "price": 197.0,
                "price_in_cash": 187.15,
                "qty": 0,
                "side_image": "https://media.eotica.com.br/catalog/product/o/c/oculos-181-mmbq1090p-c4-1-rn.jpg",
                "sku": "30-2024-MMBQ1090_C4",
                "toast": "0"
            },
            "_type": "product"
        }
    ],
    "max_score": 1.0,
    "total": 10416
},
"timed_out": false,
"took": 1
}
```

Comment: Do you have `genre`  with value `Feminino`.  Can you show some sample documents?

Comment: Keep in mind that with `not_analyzed` fields, your searches will be case-sensitive. I would recommend normalizing the case (e.g. lowercase everything) before indexing into ES, and perform the same normalization on your searches for more consistent results.

Comment: Added a output example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.

The problem is the Standard Analyzer.

An analyzer of type standard is built using the Standard Tokenizer with the Standard Token Filter, **Lower Case Token Filter**, and Stop Token Filter.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html

So, the query:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://172.17.0.2:9200/products/_search?pretty' -d '
{"query" : {
"filtered" : { 
    "query" : {
        "match_all" : {} 
    },
    "filter" : {
        "term" : { 
            "genre" : "feminino"
        }
    }
}
```

}
    }'

work very good.